# How to set Authorization header to call rest api in android?

Tags: php, android, json, rest

I have created a test rest **API** in my xampp local server. I performed a some task like register of user, login user etc.
When user register it's create a **api_key** for registered user.When user try to perform to add the task at the time I used a authenticate function which get the unique id of user based on the **api_key**.

Here is my authentication function in php:

```
function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route){
        //Getting request header
        $headers=apache_request_headers();
        $response=array();
        $app=\Slim\Slim::getInstance();


        //Verifying authorization Header

        if(isset($headers['Authorization'])){
            $db=new DbHandler();

            //Get api key
            $api_key=$headers['Authorization'];

            //validating api key

            if(!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)){
                //Api key is not present in users table
                $response["error"]=TRUE;
                $response["message"]="Access_denied! Invalid api key";
                echoRespnse(401,$response);
                $app->stop();
            }
            else{
                global $student_id;

                //getUser primary key id

                $user=$db->getUserId($api_key);
                if($user!=NULL){
                    $student_id=$user['id'];
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            //api key is missing in header
            $response["error"]=TRUE;
            $response["message"]="Api key is missing";
            echoRespnse(400,$response);
            $api->stop();
        }
    }
```

Here is my **`IsValidApiKey()`** function in php.Which check api_key is valid or not which I entered in header while I request to my local Server.

```
public function isValidApiKey($api_key) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id from student WHERE api_key = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $api_key);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        return $num_rows > 0;
    }
```

Here is tasks which add the task in my db-table:

```
$app->post('/tasks','authenticate',function() use ($app){
        //Check for required params
        verifyRequiredParams(array('task'));

        $response=array();
        $task=$app->request->post('task');
        global $user_id;
        $db=new DbHandler();

        //Creating new task

        $task_id=$db->createTask($user_id,$task);

        if($task_id!=NULL){
            $response["error"]=FALSE;
            $response["message"]="Task created successfully";
            $response["task_id"]=$task_id;
        }
        else{
            $response["error"]=TRUE;
            $response["message"]="Failed to create a task. please, try again!!";

        }
        echoRespnse(201,$response);

    });
```

In above tasks I used my authenticate function.It means it check this api_key use has already registered or not and if it is then add the task in my task table otherwise, it generate api key is missing.

Here is my **database table**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password_hash` text NOT NULL,
  `api_key` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
);
```

When I perform this operation using Advance API client add-one it work because I passed api_key in it's header.

Ii want to add the task using my android application, how can I add the **api_key** in header so that I can add the task using android application?

Comment: are you using any libraries to make requests in your android app ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost( "your_api_url" );
post.addHeader( "Auth-Secret-Key" , "your_auth_secret_key" );
```

Also, you can refer [this](http://hc.apache.org/) documentation for more info.

Comment: Which request method are you using? GET, POST or any other?

Comment: HttpPost, not supported after api 23, android recommend to use URL connection

Comment: forgot about what i need to use. you are right. try to solve this issue.

Comment: what else blocking you now ?

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpURlConnection as follows :

```
URL myURL = new URL("yoururl");
HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myURL.openConnection();

myURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");//  change as your requested method
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + postData.getBytes().length);
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
```

Comment: What is the meaning of basicAuth.

Comment: I clearly specify the api_key is different for different user. Refer this url

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this...

```
public static JSONObject post(Context mContext, String REQUEST_URL,Map<String, Object> params) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(REQUEST_URL);
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("auth1", GPLUS_EmailID);
        connection.setRequestProperty("auth2", GPLUS_AccessToken);
        connection.setRequestProperty("auth4", GCM_token);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
        connection.connect();
        StringBuilder sb;
        int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using URLConnection**

```
String credentials = username + ":" + password;
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(credentials.getBytes()));
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

Comment: Not understand my question well.

Comment: Refer this url: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/

Comment: I don't want to set the header at the time of login. i want to check add my header when i adding the tasks.

Comment: This can be done using Advance rest client add-one. But i want tot add tasks using my android app.

Comment: Can you share your android code that is trying to set authorization header while making API calls?

Comment: Please refer url thet i sent to you.